# Finding the integers modulo $n$ such that $x+y=2$, $2x-3y=3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Determine the integers $n$ for which $\mathbb Z_n$, the set of integers modulo $n$, contains elements $x$ and $y$, such that $x+y=2$, $2x-3y=3$.
Some help will be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$x + y = 2 \iff 2x - 3(2-x) = 3 \iff 5x = 9$$

This equation has a solution when...

Comment: the eqn ax=b has a solution in Zn iff gcd(a,n)=1 (I just found out). So ,that eqn has a solution iff gcd(5,n)=1.Meaning the n that we are looking for are those integers that are relatively prime to 5.

Comment: @user65541 Note that one needs both directions, i.e. not only $\implies$ but $\iff\!\!,\ $ see my answer. $\ \ $

Comment: @MathGems: Good catch.  Thanks!

Comment: @user65541: Exactly right.

Comment: @user65541 you are almost right, $ax\equiv b\pmod n$ has a solution iff $\gcd(a,n)|b$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\rm\,\ \exists\, x,y\!:\,\begin{array}{r}\rm 2x-3y\equiv3\\ \rm x+y\equiv2\end{array}\!\iff\! \exists\, x,y\!: \begin{array}{r}5y\equiv1\\ \rm x+y\equiv2 \rm \end{array}\!\iff\!  \exists\, y\!:\ 5y\equiv1\!\iff gcd(5,n)=1$